# Why didn't Zion build more hovercraft and try to invade Machine City?

Tags: the-matrix

If I am correct, Zion had nine hovercraft at the time the One was about to go to the Architect. Five of them got destroyed by an EMP by Smith/Bane, the *Nebuchadnezzar* and the *Vigilant* were destroyed by other means, and finally there remained Niobe's *Logos* and Roland's *Hammer*. I guess if all ships survived, the battle of Zion could have been won by the humans and Zion be successfully defended (without Anderson's intervention).

If Zion built even more hovercraft, would they have enough EMPs to invade and destroy Machine City? How many EMPs would be needed to attack Machine City, assuming the invader hovercraft go up above the clouds at first and then restart them when falling towards Machine City, like the *Logos* did it?

Comment: The entire human race attempted to invade the Machine city and were wiped out. What makes you think that a smattering of rebels could manage it?

Comment: Note that the Battle of Zion would have taken marginally *longer* if Smith/Bane hadn't disabled the ships, not that the humans would have won.

Comment: @Valorum They tried with nukes, not with the EMPs of hovercraft. A hovercraft's EMP is very powerful. If they had all hovercraft at Zion they would probably have "killed" off all the 250,000 sentinels invading the city, since that single EMP could destroy thousands of them, not to mention the EMUs also destroyed many of them already.

Comment: I think you're dramatically overestimating the power of these EMPs

Comment: @Valorum I'm asking how many of these EMPs would suffice to destroy the Machine City. As for the battle of Zion, I believe all 9 hovercraft could have saved it if firing their EMPs at correct times. Or maybe they would have disabled enough sentinels before the actual battle, if Smith in Bane didn't intervene, and the rest would retreat.

Comment: The simplest way to generate an EMP blast is to detonate a nuke. So if nukes couldn't it, then I don't think non-nuke EMPs are going to either.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but the machine war bit about nukes doesn’t make a whole lotta sense, they mention the heat and the blast, but the EARLY 01 machines were mostly unaffected, but 400-600 years later? EMPs kill machines all the time

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo - The future EMPs appear to be some sort of pulsed weapon.

Answer (score 2):

The range of the EMPs is relatively limited. The hovercraft are able to see things (on their scanners and visual) that they can't zap.

> **Link:** What are they doing?
> **Trinity:** They’re just out of EMP range.
> **Neo:** It’s a bomb. We have to get out of here. Now.

It stands to reason that if the range is only a globe a few hundred feet in diameter (and assuming the machine city hasn't grown dramatically since it was first founded, which seems a really big and unlikely assumption), you'd need *thousands* of ships to cover the city, and that assumes that the tens of thousands of squiddies and other machines that are outside the city (tending to the City's defences, managing the Matrix towers and the Fetus Fields, for example) wouldn't just come and kill them afterwards.

[image]

Not to mention that the whole point of Zion City is that it's a trap designed to collect malcontents. Presumably the resources that are made available in the near vicinity of Zion are very closely controlled by the Machines to prevent precisely what you're suggesting.

Comment: Isn't Zion rebuilt each time at a different location? And if you went up through the shadow, the machines would all be destroyed in the EMP up there, which saved the Logos when doing this.

Comment: @Betternottell - My assumption is that the machines clean up Zion after each attack and then The One (after a respectable amount of time wandering around in the wilderness with his followers) "*discovers it*". That would also explain the presence of the huge life-supporting machines that the head of the Zion Council admits that he doesn't understand.

Comment: I don't remember where I have that from but afaik Zion is being destroyed completely, with no trace left. As for the scenario you're quoting, the machines are really fast, and it gets some time to make an EMP ready. Maybe the EMP can have a radius of up to half a mile. Do we know how broad and how deep Zion is (from the gate to the other side, and from the roof to the Temple ground)? The Hammer's EMP disabled every attacking machine in Zion, even those who fled (except for the 2nd driller, obviously).

Comment: The Hammer's EMP destroyed all of the squids in the dock, and the immediate vicinity above. It doesn't seem to have destroyed those in the waiting area above that, as evidenced by the flood of them that come through only a few minutes later.

Comment: And councillor Hammann isn't the head of the Zion council, it's this queen/president at the center among the councillors.

Comment: Right, it destroyed just those _in_ Zion and those fleeing.

Comment: What is the scale of your image of Machine city? We don't know how long a mile is in your image, do we?

Comment: @Betternottell - I'm assuming those three lines near the top are roads.

Comment: But we dunno how broad they are.

Comment: @Betternottell - Well, in that case the answer might be 'thousands'. If they're ten lane highways, the answer would be 'tens of thousands'. Either way, given the poverty of materials to work with, the answer (from the perspective of the Zionese rebels) is simply *'an insurmountable number'*

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It would require too many resources from Zion and not be able to render the desired outcome.

Sending a large number of hovercrafts to blast some EMPs is pretty much a suicidal mission, mainly for the hovercrafts. Getting close enough to the center of the Machine City would most likely bring casualties among both the crafts and their crews.
Keep in mind that the EMPs will also affect the hovercrafts if they aren't all precisely synchronized. This is where I would guarantee the loss of many crafts.
Most importantly, do we know that Deus Ex Machina isn't prepared for a possible EMP attack?

A much easier alternative would've been to detonate a nuclear weapon just above Zero-One. A high-altitude detonation can create a very large radius EMP. For example, a 1.4Mt at 400km altitude can create an EMP radius of up to 1500km (900miles). This is a much more effective approach to EMP the machines out of existence. The only problem would be to successfully deliver the payload.

Possible risks:

- Deus Ex Machina could be protected against such an EMP attack resulting into a more aggressive war conducted by the machines.
- How do we know that there are not multiple copies of the Deus Ex Machina's code? Even though Deus controls all the machines, we see what resembles the Borg, a hive behavior. Its code could be backed up throughout the machines.
- What if the destruction of Deus Ex Machina or the majority of the Machine City would result in the failure of the fetus fields and/or the power plant? This failure will lead to the death of all those people who are plugged in and still part of the Matrix. We can see that Zion and the free people are not actually willing to accept that kind of outcome since Neo and Deus Ex Machina come to an agreement to save the machines, Zion, and the ones that are still in.

From my observation, the people are aware they cannot defeat the machines through a "ground war" by attacking their headquarters. The machines have superiority in numbers and technology. Reason why the humans have engaged in a cyberwarfare.

Ultimately, a full on attack on Zero One, with or without EMPs, is not something that Zion can engage in.

Comment: The humans nations already used nukes on Zero:One during the Machine was depicted in The Second Renaissance, Part II. They're described as being almost entirely ineffective

Comment: If the Matrix power plants got destroyed, Machine City would run out of energy. Many machines would fail, maybe to the point that the Resistance can defeat the rest.

Comment: @Betternottell I was referring to the possibility of failure, not destruction. Based on what the Architect said "There are levels of survival we are prepared to accept", I do not believe the destruction of the power plant could bring down the machines.

Comment: @Valorum There were 2 problems with the nuclear bombardment: the machines were hiding deep underground and fallout doesn't really affect machines. Only some machines were taken out. The question was regarding using EMPs, which is what a high altitude nuclear explosion can generate. Ground detonations are not that effective.

Comment: @slybloty But they would bomb the Machine City primarily. Your hypothetical scenario is just a side effect of that. Everything altogether might lead to winning the war for humans.

Comment: @Betternottell - Sure. Unless the machines have invested a few hours EMP hardening everything machine in sight with a few quid's worth of tin foil.